# Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, heroku

here are logs

```
enter code here

git push heroku-dev masterCounting objects: 29, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 2.16 KiB, done.
Total 21 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
  Installing rails_log_stdout... done

-----> Installing gem rails 2.3.8 from http://rubygems.org
  Successfully installed activesupport-2.3.8
  Successfully installed activerecord-2.3.8
  Successfully installed rack-1.1.2
  Successfully installed actionpack-2.3.8
  Successfully installed actionmailer-2.3.8
  Successfully installed activeresource-2.3.8
  Successfully installed rails-2.3.8
  7 gems installed

-----> Installing gem ruport 1.6.3 from http://rubygems.org
  ERROR:  Error installing ruport:
     hoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.4. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gem

To git@heroku.com:dev-presaletoday.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

any idea?

Comment: What happens when you update RubyGems?